# Dismiss mailComposeController

Tags: objective-c, mfmailcomposer

I am trying to dismiss the mail from my app after it's done if user sends or cancels.
But for some reasone this never dismisses. I tried almost everything.
I have also logged this so I will see if it went to dissmiss method. And the problem is there since it never enters the dismiss method.

What am i doing wrong???

```
- (IBAction)sendmail:(id)sender{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);

    if ( [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] ) {
        MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailComposer.delegate = self;
        [mailComposer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"attachment.jpg"];

        [mailComposer setSubject:@"Hello from My App!"];

        NSString *emailBody = @"Sent from My App, Still not in AppStore!";
        [mailComposer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }
}

-(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{ 
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    NSLog (@"mail finished"); // NEVER REACHES THIS POINT.
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could replace this line:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

with the following line:

```
[controller dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

`MFMailComposeViewController` class inherits from `UINavigationController` and so its delegate property is 'delegate' for navigation controller 'part' of the class. To handle specific mail composer delegate methods you need to set your object as `mailComposeDelegate` property:

```
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

## SWIFT 5.0:

If you implement the MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate protocol, you only have to contain the following function in ViewController:

```
func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) 
{
   controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

This function handles everything for you. If the user sends the email the view disappears automatically.
Any further information:
[mailComposeController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui/mfmailcomposeviewcontrollerdelegate/1616880-mailcomposecontroller)